# Does this proof on the addition of inequalities work?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I was reading this and started to do a few proofs https://www.math.purdue.edu/academic/files/courses/2007fall/MA301/MA301Ch2.pdf
Here is my proof that inequalities add

If a < b & c < d, then a+c < b+d

proof:

a < b therefore a+c < b+c (due to additivity)

c < d therefore c+b < d+b (due to additivity)

if d+b > c+b and b+c > a+c then d+b > a+c (due to Transitivity)

Q.E.D.

Is this proof satisfactory? Besides this, is it written professionally?

Comment: You proof looks fine to me. As far as I'm concerned, it's written professionally. It's basically the way I would write a proof if I were asked to prove the inequalities statement. Is there anything in particular you're concerned about being unsatisfactory or unprofessional?

Comment: No, I'm just not a professional mathematician so I really only have a vague idea of what to do(like end proofs with Q.E.D.). If anything, though, I think I might have been most unsure about writing (due to [insert axiom]). I'm glad that this is okay though, thank you.